# Can I access an image object in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a custom image control that gets rendered like this

```
<img id="2344324_Img" />
```

I am accessing this image in my HTML 5 canvas object like this:

```
var imgOne = new Image();
imgOne = document.getElementById('2344324_Img');
imgOne.onload = function() {
  // ..some code

  canvas.drawImage(this, 20, 20);
};
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: Careful with ids with capital letters; css doesn't always like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the `<img>` tag in your markup and intend to access it with `getElementById()`, there is no need to call `new Image()`:

```
<img id="2344324_Img"/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
// Don't need this...
//var imgOne = new Image();

// Instead just do:
var imgOne = document.getElementById('2344324_Img');
imgOne.onload = function() {
  ..some code
  canvas.drawImage(this, 20, 20);

  // Should be accessible either via `this` or `imgOne`
  //canvas.drawImage(imgOne, 20, 20);
}
</script>
```